# How can I chunkload on a server running from my own computer without requiring client-side mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a really fast computer, so resources isn't an issue, but what I want is to be able to chunkload my VANILLA world from a SMP / bukkit /etc., but bukkit's download pages have been taken down, so probably not bukkit. I just want to load my vanilla farms (Mob farm, sugar cane farm) and not have issues.

Comment: `/spreadplayers` command will force load chunks in specified area, but I'm not exactly sure how this will work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking for, you want to be able to keep chunks around your farm and such loaded so they can still grow while you're away?

You could install [this Bukkit mod](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/chunkloader/), which allows you to keep chunks loaded via commands.

These are the relevant commands:

```
User-related commands   Description
/ChunkLoader help       help command listing all commands
/ChunkLoader set        set the current chunk at your location as part of the chunk loader
/ChunkLoader remove     removes the current chunk at your location as part of the chunk loader
/ChunkLoader list       List all chunks added to ChunkLoader
```

I've never used this mod, so I don't know about how well it performs, but it seems to have been downloaded quite a bit, so it might be worth a try.

Comment: That does answer my question, if you can find a link / torrent for bukkit